# How to convert string to DTO in Java

Tags: java, spring

How to convert string to DTO.

I am doing some db fetch and getting String.

```
List<String> tempString = myRepo.getData(str);
```

I am getting string here like this

```
{"LastName": "Ben",  "FirstName": "David", "EmailAddress": "david@gravatar.com"}
```

now I want to convertto dto.

my dto will be like this.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class UserDTO {

   
    @JsonProperty("FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("LastName")
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty("EmailAddress")
    private String email;


}
```

Now here is what I am trying but not getting sucees, anything I am missing here.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
UserDTO userdeto;
try{
    userdeto= mapper.readValue(tempString.get(i), UserDTO.class);
}
```

but this is wrong here I. any other way to get this.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I am expecting that string to be DTO object.

Comment: What happens when you call `readValue` in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Java 8**

It seems that you are getting list of String from the database, you can convert the list of string into list of UserDTO by this approach.

**Approach Here:**

*Here I have `stream` the list of string and convert each `String` into `UserDTO` type using the `map()` operation and collecting it as a list of UserDTO.*

where, `tempString` is the list that you are preparing from the db *(it is hardcoded in my case for the solution purpose)*

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> tempString = new ArrayList<>();
        tempString.add("{\"LastName\": \"Ben\",  \"FirstName\": \"David\", \"EmailAddress\": \"david@gravatar.com\"}");
        tempString.add("{\"LastName\": \"Ben2\",  \"FirstName\": \"David1\", \"EmailAddress\": \"david1@gravatar.com\"}");
        tempString.add("{\"LastName\": \"Ben3\",  \"FirstName\": \"David2\", \"EmailAddress\": \"david2@gravatar.com\"}");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<UserDTO> userDtoList = tempString.stream().map(x -> {
            UserDTO userDto = null;
            try {
                userDto = mapper.readValue(x, UserDTO.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                System.out.println("exception"+e);
            }
            return userDto;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(userDtoList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[UserDTO(firstName=David, lastName=Ben, email=david@gravatar.com), UserDTO(firstName=David1, lastName=Ben2, email=david1@gravatar.com), UserDTO(firstName=David2, lastName=Ben3, email=david2@gravatar.com)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using spring you can directly convert to List UserDTO from the repository itself if you can extend your Repository from JpaRepository.

```js
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT new com.UserDTO(u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email) FROM USER u WHERE u.user_id= :UserId ")
        List<UserDTO> getData(@Param("userId")  userId);
}
```

You need to have a matching constructor in your DTO and need provide full package name in the query.